# How do I make edge(v1, v2) list in C++ without STL

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to make a list of  edge with vertex1 and vertex2.

I don't want to use any stl library. However I'm thinking of a linked list with edge information.  Is there a better way to represent edge list without stl?

Comment: Are the edges connecting vertices (geometry) https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Edge_(geometry) ?

Comment: @amdn yes, edges are made up of (vertex1,vertex2)

Comment: The standard library is an integral part of C++, why not use it ?

Comment: @amdn I'm from Korea and there is a software coding test when I'm trying to enter Samsung. I heard that it allows iostream only if I'm right. So I was curious of what methods there are as alternatives for preparing the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use standard library when possible. But if you have restriction then you may have several ways

1. Using two parallel array.
2. Using array of structure.
3. Using Linked list

You may declare structure like

```
struct edge{ 
    int vertex1;
    int vertex2;
 }
```